# Is there a way to separate a column containing multiple data sets?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm new to this and the dataframe I'm currently working with has four columns containing data in just object datatype. The last column contains multiple data points...

i.e. the first row, last column contains:

```
[{"year":"1901","a":"A","b":"B"}]   #printed in this format
```

Is there a way so I can create a new column containing just the year? i.e. isolate this data

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

With pandas, you can add a new column the same way you add a value to a dictionary.
So this should work for you.

```
df['year'] = [i[0]['year'] for i in df['last_column']]
```

Comment: Thank you! I've just tried this and it's returned the error - 'list indices must be integers or slices, not str' any ideas how to get round this

Comment: I edited the answer and this should work for you. I think based on the information in your question, the element i inside the list comprehension is a list itself so an index position(```[0]```), must be referenced.

Comment: you can do this simpler using the df.apply. you dont need to write a list comprehension

Answer (score 0):

You can use the df.apply() to get the dictionary value and assign it to a new column.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['Jack','Jill','Moon','Wall','Hill'],
                   'col2':[100,200,300,400,500],
                   'col3':[{"year":"1901","a":"A","b":"B"},
                           {"year":"1902","c":"C","d":"D"},
                           {"year":"1903","e":"E","f":"F"},
                           {"year":"1904","g":"G","h":"H"},
                           {"year":"1905","i":"I","j":"J"}] })

print (df)

df['year'] = df['col3'].apply(lambda x: x['year'])
print (df)
```

Output for the above code:

Original DataFrame:

```
   col1  col2                                  col3
0  Jack   100  {'year': '1901', 'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}
1  Jill   200  {'year': '1902', 'c': 'C', 'd': 'D'}
2  Moon   300  {'year': '1903', 'e': 'E', 'f': 'F'}
3  Wall   400  {'year': '1904', 'g': 'G', 'h': 'H'}
4  Hill   500  {'year': '1905', 'i': 'I', 'j': 'J'}
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
   col1  col2                                  col3  year
0  Jack   100  {'year': '1901', 'a': 'A', 'b': 'B'}  1901
1  Jill   200  {'year': '1902', 'c': 'C', 'd': 'D'}  1902
2  Moon   300  {'year': '1903', 'e': 'E', 'f': 'F'}  1903
3  Wall   400  {'year': '1904', 'g': 'G', 'h': 'H'}  1904
4  Hill   500  {'year': '1905', 'i': 'I', 'j': 'J'}  1905
```